# How do I make wave texture node in the shape I want?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

[image]

[image]

I want it to look like a pages in the same shape as the top

Comment: Easiest way to get it to follow this shape is to use UV coordinates.

Comment: Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/235351/edit) your question and add the images directly to it so readers get a quick overview. If the external links break/go offline then no one knows what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

If your pages are one object, with bounding-box aligned to the front face,you could use an *RGB Curves* node in some way like this:

[image]

Comment: ....but it would be more conventional to UV unwrap your object

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put a mapping node in between wave texture and texture coordinate to adjust scale,rotation,and location.[image]